# Print specific number of lines furthest from the current pattern match and just before matching another pattern

Tags: regex, perl, bash, scripting, awk

I have a tab delimited file such as the one below. I want to find the specific number of minimum values in a group. The group starts after finding E in the last column. For example, I want to print two lines (records) that are furthest from, first occurrence of E, the items are sorted in column with E. Here Jack's case and also after second occurrence of E in Gareth's case.

```
Jack    2   98  E
Jones   6   25  8.11
Mike    8   11  5.22
Jasmine 5   7   4
Simran  5   7   3
Gareth  1   85  E
Jones   4   76  178.32
Mark    11  12  157.3
Steve   17  8   88.5
Clarke  3   7   12.3
Vid     3   7   2.3
```

I want my result to be

```
Jasmine 5   7   4
Simaran 5   7   3
Clarke  3   7   12.3
Vid     3   7   2.3
```

There can be different number of records in a group. I tried with grep

```
grep -B 2 F$ inputfile.txt
```

But it repeats the results with E and also does not work with the last record.

Comment: There is no `F` in the last column.

Comment: @TLP : that typo is now fixed. Thanks !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using arrays of arrays in Gnu Awk version 4, you can try

```
gawk -vnum=2 -f e.awk input.txt
```

where `e.awk` is:

```
$4=="E" {
    N[j++]=i
    i=0
}
{
    l[j][++i]=$0
}

END {
    N[j]=i; ngr=j
    for (i=1; i<=ngr; i++) {
        m=N[i]
        for (j=m-num+1; j<=m; j++)
            print l[i][j]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

quick & dirty:

```
kent$  awk '/E$/&&a&&b{print b RS a;a=b="";next}{b=a;a=$0}END{print b RS a}' file
Jasmine 5   7   4
Simran  5   7   3
Clarke  3   7   12.3
Vid     3   7   2.3
```

Comment: Dirty indeed, how can I do minimum ten records in this dirty case.

Comment: @lovedynasty build an array, and maintain the element. or push all entries in a "block" into an array, and pick the entries you need

Answer (score 1):

I don't see an F in you last column. But assuming you want to get every 2 lines above a line ending in E:

```
grep -B2 'E$' <(cat inputfile.txt;echo "E")|sed "/E$\|^--/d"
```

Should do the trick

- `'E$'` look for an "E" at the end of a line
- the `-B2` gets the 2 lines before as well
- `<(cat inputfile.txt;echo "E")` add an "E" as last line to match the last ones as well (this does not chage the actual file)
- `sed "/E$\|^--/d"` delete all lines ending in "E" or beginning with "--" (separator of grep)

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '$2 ~/5|3/ && $3 ~/7/' file
Jasmine 5   7   4
Simran  5   7   3
Clarke  3   7   12.3
Vid     3   7   2.3
```